# Self-referencing table - how to get results as one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, self-referencing-table

I have a table like this

[image]

Please forgive the column names they are driven by internal standards. What I would like to know is how to query this self-referencing table so the output is something like this:

```
| PARENT REASON |    CHILD REASON  |
| ---------------------------------|
| Electrical    | Wire Broke       |
| Electrical    | Fuse Blown       |
| Mechanical    | Bad Gear         |
| Mechanical    | Bolt Broke       |
```

You help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any chance that you'll need to handle a deeper search, e.g. Electrical > Fuse Blown > Insulation Failure? A Common Table Expression (CTE) can handle recursion.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT T2.strReason as [PARENT REASON], T1.strReason as [CHILD REASON]
FROM IngTable as T1
JOIN IngTable as T2
  ON T1.IngReasonParent = T2.IngReason
```

Comment: var query =
 
    from T1 in IngTable

    join T2 in IngTable on T1.IngReasonParent = T2.IngReasonParent

    Select T2.strReason, T1.strReason

should work

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should break that apart into a category table, but...

```
SELECT SELECT a.strReason as [PARENT REASON], b.strReason as [CHILD REASON]
FROM table1 AS a 
INNER JOIN table1 as b ON b.lngReasonParent = a.lngReason
```